# Wayland and GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-unity, wayland

I was wondering if it would be possible to use Wayland with GNOME shell. I updated to Natty, and I'm not too fond of Unity. I've been wanting to experiment with Wayland (I'm forced to use the open-source drivers under 11.04 anyway), and I'm always for bringing in new stuff.

Does anyone know about compatibility? Does anyone have advice for switching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wayland in Natty doesn't support the X11 protocol you'll need a modified version of Gnome Shell that can use Wayland instead of X11. I don't think there is one yet.

Unity isn't using Wayland in Natty either.

If you don't like Unity you can still use a traditional Gnome2 environment in Nutty, or compile Gnome-Shell yourself (it's not included in Natty for stability reasons).